# Replace the first value in each cell of a cell array with the value from another cell array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, watermark

I have a cell array containing the eigenvalues of a set of matrices. I have removed the first value from each of the cells in this array, and placed them in a matrix. These values are then manipulated via a set of thresholds based on a watermark image. I have then reconverted matrix of values to a cell array. I would now like to place the values from these new cells into the corresponding first location of the cells in the old array. Any ideas on how to do this?  I've seen quite a few methods for searching and replacing based on rules, but none that simply do a one-to-one replacement.  I'm just hoping that it's possible.

Function Code follows: (The last line there is the trouble)

```
    function D = fun(D,W)
    Q = 5;
    [i,j] = size(D)
    F = cellfun(@(c) c(1), D); % grab the first value from each cell
    disp(F); % Debug check
    for a = 1:i % Process the values
       for b = 1:j
       Z = mod(F(a,b),Q); 
         if W(a,b) == 0
             if Z<(3*Q)/4;
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)+Q/4-Z;
             else
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)+5*Q/4-Z;
             end 
         else 
             if Z<Q/4;
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)-Q/4+Z;
             else
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)+3*Q/4-Z;
             end
         end
      end
   end
   disp(F); % Debug check
   F = num2cell(F); % Make the new cell array
   disp(F); % Debug Check
   D{1,1} = cellfun(@(F) F{1,1}, F);    % No clue what to do here
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the simplest solution for what you want to achieve is the following:

```
    function D = fun(D,W)
    Q = 5;
    [i,j] = size(D)
    F = cellfun(@(c) c(1), D); % grab the first value from each cell
    disp(F); % Debug check
    for a = 1:i % Process the values
       for b = 1:j
       Z = mod(F(a,b),Q); 
         if W(a,b) == 0
             if Z<(3*Q)/4;
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)+Q/4-Z;
             else
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)+5*Q/4-Z;
             end 
         else 
             if Z<Q/4;
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)-Q/4+Z;
             else
                F(a,b) = F(a,b)+3*Q/4-Z;
             end
         end
         D{a,b}(1) = F(a,b)
      end
   end

   end
```

So all I did was assign the value of F(a,b) into the first element of D{a,b} within the loop where you manipulate F - which you can do  as the elements of F are independent anyway. 
Using matlab built-in functions like `cellfun` aren't always faster than an explicit loop anyway. Hope this helps.